# Enable/Disable checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to enable a group of checkboxes only if another checkbox is checked. Otherwise, I want them to remain disabled.

Here is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    enable_cb();
    $("#university").click(enable_cb);
  });

  function enable_cb() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('input.uni').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('input.uni').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test-form" novalidate>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="university" id="university"/>
University<br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="1" />
A<br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="2" />
B<br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="3" />
C<br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="3" />
D<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="buildings" />
Buildings<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="offices"  />
Offices<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="halls"  />
Halls<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="labs"  />
Labs<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="studios" />
Studios<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="machines"  />
Machines<br>
<input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="facilities"  />
Facilities<br>
</form>
```

Why does this not work for me?

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: It is working here https://jsfiddle.net/yhynuv4L/ . Can you explain how it is not working?

Comment: Your first call to `enable_cb();` doesn't have a `this` context, add one with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on()` method instead and use the 'click' trigger. Check Below snippet

```js
function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('input.uni').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('input.uni').prop('disabled', true);
  }
}


$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#university").on('click',enable_cb);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test-form" novalidate>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="university" id="university" />University<br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="1" />A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="2" />B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="3" />C<br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" class="uni" value="3" />D<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="buildings" />Buildings<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="offices" />Offices<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="halls" />Halls<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="labs" />Labs<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="studios" />Studios<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="machines" />Machines<br>
  <input name="table[]" type="checkbox" value="facilities" />Facilities<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Owwwh finally got that to work, Thank you so much ^^